# Cant use key-value structure in post request

Tags: python, node.js, request

I got a problem with the post request. This is my Pythonscript which sends `myobj` to the url:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/test'
myobj = {'somekey':[{'name':'Leon','age':12},{'name':'Aley','age':15}]}
x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)

print(x.text)
```

In my api, he gives me the following output:
`{ somekey: [ 'name', 'age', 'name', 'age' ] }` but I need `{'somekey':[{'name':'Leon','age':12},{'name':'Aley','age':15}]}`

Sorry, if I am completly lost.

Comment: Doesn't this rather depend on the implementation of your API? You **may** find a difference if you POST with *json=* instead of *data=*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is the following python code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/test'
myobj = {'somekey':"[{'name':'Leon','age':12},{'name':'Aley','age':15}]"}
x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)

print(x.text)
```

and the `string` of somekey has to be parsed: `JSON.parse(data.somekey)`